# How to have Flutter update Android emulator in VS code?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to learn Flutter to make a basic app but I have run into a problem. I do not have a mac book so as I was following the YouTube video I realized it was not going to be as simple as plugging in the iOS device. So I have downloaded the Android emulator and the flutter demo work perfectly fine, when launching and running from VS Code.

However I am having an issue where any changes I make are not reflecting to the emulator. I have tried doing the "hot restart" and nothing changes. I have noticed that if I change the code in Android Studio that the app does in fact update, but is there anyway to make this possible in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Dart` and `Flutter` extensions for Visual Studio code. Go to the extensions tab on the left side and search for them. You should be able to install them and then use F5 to hot-reload.

You can find the extensions here: [Flutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter) and [Dart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code)

I would also advise you to use an extension to launch the Android and iOS emulators: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate

Comment: Yes these extensions are already installed but still having issue

Comment: Are you launching the Android Emulator from VSCode as well? It only works for me if it's launched from there.

Comment: yes i am using the command flutter emulator --launch Nexus 6 P, then i cd to the app location and do flutter run, but i still get the flutter demo showing up on the emulator which is odd

Comment: I am a bit confused with your last comment. So it works from the command line, but not from VSCode right? And you are indeed launching the Android Emulator initially from VSCode? I use this extention: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate
When I use that and launch the emulator from VSCode, then the F5 hot reload works great.

Comment: I was running everything through VS code, with command flutter emulator --launch Nexus 6 P. Let me try that extension and see if it works

Comment: I am having trouble with the path so that the extension works properly, thank you for your help but i will try again in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I was having a *similar* issue.

In my case I fixed this by going in **Settings > search for hot reload > and where it says DART: flutter hot reload on save, I put Always.**

So when you save *it will automatically do it for you*.

Another way that helped here was to edit the shortcut for Cmd+R to the restart and code with the debug on.

[Preferences > Keyboard Shortcut > Search for Restart and edit this Keybiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zENu.png)

And you always can change back this easy.
I hope it helped someone...

:)